# How can I do Camera Tracking of turnaround Camera Shot?

Tags: after-effects, tracking, compositing, visual-effects, 360video

Hope you are doing well.

I am working on a **Slow Motion Video** in which Camera is **rotating around** a person on a dolly. I want to do **3D Camera Tracking** of this Shot. I have tried it Using **Adobe After Effects Camera Tracker** but I am getting following error:

"Unable to solve camera"

I am not sure what to do about it. So here I need help with that, I need suggestions, and guidelines about how to do it actually and which software should I use for this kind of Camera Tracking.

This is 
[Video for Camera Tracking](https://youtu.be/dJKyP1_CMl8)

Please have a look at above video and help me to do Camera Tracking.

Waiting for response.

Thanks

Comment: I just wanted to comment that your footage looks awesome! I wish there was more light on the kicker, but other than that it's dynamic, smooth and excellent. I hope someone provides you with a camera-tracking solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can check PFTrack.
Also there are another good trackers options like Boujou, Syntheyes, Mocha Pro, Match mover, 3D Equializer ...
NukeX has also a good tracking suite.